# how can I sort certain values in one column of one csv file as a result of multiple csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm new to use Python. I would like to handle 114 csv file as my simulation results.
At this moment, I calculate average of each csv file and make one csv file.
Based on above file, I want to extract only 4 values from below csv file.

```
Results/1a\001a.csv,3.729555644876643e-05,-8.489722306072623e-09,0.2189213009779949,1.8189734046014334e-08,0.21661787881258218,-2.55622256504202e-05,2.957845146641823e-06,0.005881073673178551,0.001028817803792101,0.20050853330394616,5.214465733076785e-06,0.19967684452546472,-0.0010047694830277378,inf,1.4841531644318505e-05,0.02490000000000206,0.020599999999999983,0.0060000003075623785,inf,8.809984745406528e-05,0.02490000000000206,0.020599999999999983,0.0060000003075623785
Results/1a\002a.csv,0.00044266393558895027,-4.871692086408956e-07,0.491797297872664,-1.4374768245601583e-05,0.48788925514981035,-0.00011101106735340776,5.3131821116074796e-05,0.02997964996383977,0.003919473465573261,0.4467310064440727,-0.0001537532334179777,0.4451642735022221,-0.005129463501241342,inf,6.396275140922866e-05,0.024800000000015338,0.02059999999999965,0.006439365934432054,inf,0.00020025575929075146,0.024800000000015338,0.02059999999999965,0.006439365934432054
Results/1a\003a.csv,0.0013688882649255905,-5.811439696558463e-07,0.7235505352349502,-1.841992502829627e-06,0.7188667004955674,-8.354410614115703e-05,0.00018602179959436254,0.06327359925790432,0.006802051121068685,0.6573219886196483,-5.361314096898339e-05,0.6554473776013993,-0.003483470537165227,inf,0.00013162281892988633,0.02469999999999655,0.020599999999999712,0.006037445347231759,inf,0.000297761205072387,0.02469999999999655,0.020599999999999712,0.006037445347231759
Results/1a\004a.csv,0.0029087011937919977,-6.223790450501293e-07,0.944839107407674,2.120875772647082e-05,0.9396578033827917,-0.00030080025961839215,0.00043332350911585326,0.103624137395163,0.009632247232105758,0.8662811882484165,-0.00040192890174102784,0.8641474385496596,-0.0018479810684538943,inf,0.00013347284255437153,0.02460000000000782,0.020599999999999594,0.0058108412768377365,inf,0.0003949692974612218,0.02460000000000782,0.020599999999999594,0.0058108412768377365
Results/1a\005a.csv,0.005111103180682736,-2.1135229634622883e-06,1.1645656717324973,3.726801334127048e-05,1.1589843566808042,-0.0003747348409265324,0.0008320027973329297,0.14826622143687557,0.012461695552911812,1.083837242606168,3.636550037486185e-05,1.0815461970970663,-0.0027228376349728053,inf,0.00016556367820564125,0.02449999999999286,0.020599999999999615,0.005855731524347499,inf,0.000498443717769948,0.02449999999999286,0.020599999999999615,0.005855731524347499
```

My result file is result_1a.csv.
I tried to make csv file to dataframe and extract necessary values.
However, it didn't work I guess because of below reason.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table("result_1a.csv")
print(df)
df.info()
```

Please see below information.

```
[114 rows x 1 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 114 entries, 0 to 113
Data columns (total 1 columns):
dtypes: object(1)
```

1 column includes the following value[filename,u1u1,u2u2,u3u3,Mean,velocity, ....].
How can I extract only `u1u1, u2u2,u3u3` values?

Actually, it would be great to divide 1 column into several column depending on each values.
Is it possible to that in python?

Thanks to your helps in advance.

Comment: It is a good practice in these cases to provide a simple and small fake dataset instead of the actual data, it helps readability and makes it easier for people to run some tests and help you.

Answer (score 0):

for your example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("result_1a.csv")
```

you can filter the mentioned values in the column ("col_name") with:

```py
df_filtered = df[(df["col_name"]=='u1u1') | (df["col_name"]=='u2u2') | (df["col_name"]=='u3u3')]
df_filtered.index = df_filtered["col_name"]
df_filtered = df_filtered.drop(["col_name"], axis=1)
df_filtered = df_filtered.transpose()
```

The " | " marks a locigal or.

Best regards

Comment: thanks to your comment. however, it didn't work. I mentioned my file is only one column. I guess because of that reason, python can't recognized "col_name". u1u1 is just value name. It's not column title. one column included all average values from 114 csv files. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hey, for "col_name" you have to type the specific name of your column label. Pls type in: " df.columns  "  to get your column labels.

Comment: Above code, I made A index for a column in csv file because my csv file doesn't have label of the column. However, it doesn't work. I got below message.                                                                                                                    Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []                                                                                                                       Actually, my calculated csv file has only one column(114 rows * 1 columns). in one row, there are 20 values. I want to sort 4 values per row. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: So I guess with " pd.read_csv("result_1a.csv") " you get an empty frame now. (Empty DataFrame Columns[] Index[]). Please try df.columns again under reading your dataframe with "pd.read_csv("result_1a.csv",sep=',', header=0)".